# Why interface for Spring DAO classes instead of normal methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Why we need to use interface for dao or services layers instead of creating direct methods. Any specific reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides loosely coupled code. It will give implementation for the interfaces. Or if you want to give your own implementation you can do it. It is also best practise.

Answer (score 0):

Using an interface is useful for two main reasons:

- change the implementation with a new implementation
- testing the code with mock objects

In fact using an interface instead of a class decouple your code from the real implementation.